# Linux bash command to list hidden files first, then other files sorted by extension

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, ls

This page: [How can I make "ls" show dotfiles first?](https://superuser.com/questions/448291/how-can-i-make-ls-show-dotfiles-first) lets me list hidden files first, but I also wish to sort non-hidden files by "extension" e.g. all filenames ending with ".png" come after those ending with ".jpg".

ls -X does that, but the hidden files are no longer listed first (I suppose because their names begin with ".", their whole name is treated as their extension).

Is there a way to list hidden files first, and then non-hidden files sorted by extension? I'd prefer it to be wholly contained in the ls command, so that I can add further flags when needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use two commands: the first outputs the dotted files, the second lists the rest in the correct order:

```
ls -1 -d .* ; ls -X -1
```

You might need to use `'ls'` with quotes to prevent aliases from changing the behaviour.